# How can I count strings in nested arrays?

Tags: javascript

There is nested `names` array with only strings, need to loop through to find how many times each string appears. Since two elements have "bob" resulting function should return 2. How to search for the string even if array is nested?

```
var names = ["bob", ["steve", "michael", "bob", "chris"]];

function loop(){ 
    /* .... */
}

var result = loop(names, "bob");
console.log(result); // 2
```

Comment: You could either flatten the array or perhaps make use of recursion. Although can you clarify: *"...since two elements have `"bob"`"* - Are you trying to return the total number of `"bob"` strings, or the total number of elements that *contain* a `"bob"` string?

Comment: Loop through the array. If the element matches the string, add 1 to the counter. If the element is an array, recurse, and add the result to the counter. Finally, return the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [flatten](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the array and then just return the length of the filtered array.

```js
const names = ["bob", ["steve", "michael", "bob", "chris"]];

function loop ( arr, name ) {
  return arr.flat( Infinity ).filter( el => el === name ).length;
}

const result = loop(names, "bob");
console.log(result); // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Example

```js
var names = ["bob", ["steve", "michael", "bob", "chris"]];

function loop(names, searchString){ 
   var flattenArray = names.flat(Infinity);
   return flattenArray.filter(n => n === searchString).length;
}

var result = loop(names, "bob");
console.log(result); // 2
```

Comment: While I don't think it detracts from the answer at all, it might be worth pointing out that `.flat()` is relatively new and not supported by all major browsers (Edge for example). If browser support is needed for Edge/IE, consider implementing a [polyfill](https://github.com/es-shims/Array.prototype.flat).

Answer (score 1):

you can use `flatMap`

```js
var names = ["bob", ["steve", "michael", "bob", "chris"]];


console.log(names.flatMap(el => el === "bob").length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate and determine this way as well:

```
var names = ["bob", ["steve", "michael", "bob", "chris"]];
var result = 0;
function loop(names,searchElement){ 
    for (var el=0;el<names.length;el++){
        if(Array.isArray(names[el])){
            for(var elem=0;elem<names[el].length;elem++){
                if(names[elem]==searchElement){
                    result = result + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            if(names[el]==searchElement){
                result = result + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var results = loop(names, "bob");
console.log(result);
```